# Understanding Entity Framework handling of DateTimeOffset fields, TZ offsets and Update

Tags: entity-framework

We are using Entity Framework to insert and update rows in a SQL Server running on Azure. The code is also running in Azure so has a local TZ of UTC.

We send JSON from the Client with DateTimeOffsets that are from different TZs such as `26/07/2023 00:00:00 +01:00:00` which is 26th July 2023 at midnight with a TZ offset of 1hr as the client sending the data was in British Summer Time.

The entity is deserialised as expected and converted using AutoMapper to an existing entity if the entity was previously saved.

The insert code looks like this:

```
public override async Task<CommandResult> Handle(InsertObservation<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var nextIdInSequence = await this.entityIdGenerator.GetNextIdAsync(request.UserId);

    if (!nextIdInSequence.HasValue)
    {
        return CreateFailureResult("Unable to get the next ID in the sequence. Check the DB connection is available.");
    }

    request.Observation.EntityId = nextIdInSequence.Value;
    var entity = this.converter.Convert(request.Observation);
    entity.UserId = request.UserId;

    this.avatarEntityRepository.Add(entity);
    await this.avatarEntityRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Update timestamp of incoming entity
    request.Observation.Timestamp = entity.Timestamp;

    return CreateSuccessResult();
}
```

On an insert the TZ +1 (in this example) survives. However In an update scenario which runs very similar code

```
public override async Task<CommandResult> Handle(UpdateObservation<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var foundEntity = await this.avatarEntityRepository.GetByIdAsync(request.UserId, request.Observation.EntityId);

    if (foundEntity is null)
    {
        return CreateFailureResult($"Unable to update item. No entity found with userId {request.UserId} entity id {request.Observation.EntityId}");
    }

    // Update timestamp
    request.Observation.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    this.converter.Update(request.Observation, foundEntity);

    foundEntity.UserId = request.UserId;
    await this.avatarEntityRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    request.Observation.Timestamp = foundEntity.Timestamp;

    return CreateSuccessResult();
}
```

The +1 TZ is written as 25/07/2023 23:00:00 00:00:00.

The `foundEntity` and the `request.Observation` are the same after the Automapper update and at the time that SaveChangesAsync is called the TZ of +1 is present on the DateTimeOffset property yet the row in SQL Server is set to 25/07/2023 23:00:00 00:00:00. I cannot see where this is being done in the code.

I eventually turned to ChatGPT for answers and that said that this behavior on Updates is the default. Surely that is not true.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? What is ` this.converter.Update`?

Comment: It's a wrapper around the call return this.mapper.Map<TDestination>(source); where "mapper" is an Automapper.IMapper

Comment: Still a [mre] would be great (also I would argue that database should store UTCs, but this is my preference).